# Extracting the classpath entries from a jar file's manifest

Tags: bash

Sometimes I need to search for dependencies in the classpath entries in the manifest of jar files. A jar manifest with classpaths looks like this:

> ```
> Manifest-Version: 1.0
> Created-By: 1.6.0_29 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
> Class-Path: spring-aop-3.2.0.jar spring-aspects-3.2.0.jar spring-beans
>  -3.2.0.jar spring-context-3.2.0.jar spring-context-support-3.2.0.jar
>  spring-core-3.2.0.jar spring-expression-3.2.0.jar spring-instrument-3
>  .2.0.jar spring-instrument-tomcat-3.2.0.jar spring-jdbc-3.2.0.jar spr
>  ing-jms-3.2.0.jar spring-orm-3.2.0.jar spring-oxm-3.2.0.jar spring-st
>  ruts-3.2.0.jar spring-test-3.2.0.jar spring-tx-3.2.0.jar spring-web-3
>  .2.0.jar spring-webmvc-3.2.0.jar spring-webmvc-portlet-3.2.0.jar
> ```

Searching for jars in a manifest is troublesome:

1. Extract the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file from the jar
2. Re-join the split lines to make searching humanely possible

Step 2 is necessary, because of the line breaks. For example, I won't find "struts" in the above, because the word is broken in the middle.

I use this shell script to make this process easier, I call it `jar-manifest-classpath.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if test -d "$TMPDIR"; then
    :
elif test -d "$TMP"; then
    TMPDIR=$TMP
elif test -d /var/tmp; then
    TMPDIR=/var/tmp
else
    TMPDIR=/tmp
fi
workdir=$TMPDIR/$(basename "$0")-work-$$

cleanup() {
    rm -fr "$workdir"
}

mkdir -p "$workdir"
trap 'cleanup' 1 2 3 15

for jar; do
    if ! test -f $jar; then
        echo warning: not a file: $jar
        continue
    fi
    [[ $jar = /* ]] || jar=$PWD/$jar
    (
        cd "$workdir" || exit 1
        jar xf "$jar"
        sed -ne '/^Class-Path:/,$p' META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | sed -e 's/^Class-Path: //' -e 's/^ //' | tr -d '\n' | tr ' ' '\n'
    )
done

cleanup
```

For a jar file with the manifest as above, this will output:

> ```
> spring-aop-3.2.0.jar
> spring-aspects-3.2.0.jar
> spring-beans-3.2.0.jar
> spring-context-3.2.0.jar
> spring-context-support-3.2.0.jar
> spring-core-3.2.0.jar
> spring-expression-3.2.0.jar
> spring-instrument-3.2.0.jar
> spring-instrument-tomcat-3.2.0.jar
> spring-jdbc-3.2.0.jar
> spring-jms-3.2.0.jar
> spring-orm-3.2.0.jar
> spring-oxm-3.2.0.jar
> spring-struts-3.2.0.jar
> spring-test-3.2.0.jar
> spring-tx-3.2.0.jar
> spring-web-3.2.0.jar
> spring-webmvc-3.2.0.jar
> spring-webmvc-portlet-3.2.0.jar
> ```

This is much more pleasent, and perfectly `grep`-able.

Let me know if you have any ideas to improve or simplify!
(The script is part of my collection on [GitHub](https://github.com/janosgyerik/shellscripts))

Comment: It would be much easier to do this in Java, since the standard library has classes to handle JAR manifest already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would create the trap for cleanup before an action is done that needs cleanup, so change the sequence of commands. Also I would prefer signal names instead of numbers. If you add EXIT to the signal list then cleanup is called when the shell is exited, so you can remove the last line of your script (`cleanup`)

```
trap 'cleanup' EXIT SIGHUP SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGTERM
mkdir -p "$workdir"
```

If the script is called without argument or with`-?` a usage message should be displayed.

Warnings and error messages should be written to stderr(2) and not to stdout(1). This is Unix standard behaviour for a program. Otherwise you will not see the error message if you pipe the output through a `grep` command.

Comment: Excellent points, thank you! I wish you came to Code Review more often!

Answer (score 7):

Bash may not be the best tool for the job, as evidenced by the difficulty with extraction and text processing.  Although the `jar` command doesn't support extracting contents to standard output, Java does have [built-in support for parsing manifest files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/Manifest.html).  Consider writing a minimal shell wrapper to invoke a Java program:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Manifest mf = (args.length > 0) ? (new JarFile(args[0])).getManifest()
                                    : (new JarInputStream(System.in)).getManifest();
    String classPath = mf.getMainAttributes().getValue("Class-Path");
    if (classPath != null) {
        for (String dependency : classPath.split(" ")) {
            System.out.println(dependency);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A related example using this versatile approach is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2201870/230513).

Answer (score 6):

You are working quite hard to create a temp folder, but you should instead just use the right tool: `mktemp`

```
workdir=$(mktemp -d)
```

That's the safe way to create it in a way that's not going to have race conditions.

Note that `mktemp` uses the value in `$TMPDIR` (if set) as the location in which to create the folder, so it will use whatver value you have set in the code before running `mktemp`

Comment: +1 `mktemp` is the right tool, but `$TMPDIR` is the default. so `mktemp -d`should be used instead

Comment: Without `-t` `mktemp` doesn't use `$TMPDIR` though does it?

Comment: @EtanReisner - The man page says it does: *" If TEMPLATE is not specified, use tmp.XXXXXXXXXX, and --tmpdir is implied."*

Comment: For GNU/coreutils `mktemp` perhaps. Not for BSD `mktemp` (at least according to the docs I see).

Answer (score 5):

Although this script works fine with the given example and with *classpath jars* in general (jars containing only a manifest and no classes),
it will be very inefficient with jars that contain classes.
The culprit is the step that extracts the jar:

> ```
>     [[ $jar = /* ]] || jar=$PWD/$jar
>     (
>         cd "$workdir" || exit 1
>         jar xf "$jar"
>         ^^^^ not so good
> ```

The `jar xf` step like this will extract the entire `jar` file,
when the manifest file would be enough, like this:

```
        jar xf "$jar" META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

---

There is another obscure bug: 
although in the example the `Class-Path` field is the last,
it's not guaranteed to be that way.
For example this is a perfectly valid manifest,
and some implementations may generate the manifest this way:

> ```
> Manifest-Version: 1.0
> Class-Path: spring-aop-3.2.0.jar spring-aspects-3.2.0.jar spring-beans
>  -3.2.0.jar spring-context-3.2.0.jar spring-context-support-3.2.0.jar
>  spring-core-3.2.0.jar spring-expression-3.2.0.jar
> Created-By: 1.6.0_29 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
> ```

The `sed` script in the question won't handle this case well,
and the content of the `Created-By` line will end up in the output.
Although this doesn't break your ability to `grep` for names in the classpath,
the added lines are garbage, and clearly not as intended.

---

Instead of the tedious multiple `if-else`,
a more elegant and equivalent way to find a suitable temp directory:

```
for TMPDIR in "$TMPDIR" "$TMP" /var/tmp /tmp; do
    test -d "$TMPDIR" && break
done
```

*(This technique was suggested in [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174819/17433) on my other related question, by [@frostschutz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/30851/frostschutz))*

Answer (score 5):

When working with Jar files you should remember that they are just zip files with some restrictions.

As a result, there's no need to go through the whole extract-to-temp folder, and instead you can do the 'simple route':

```
unzip -q -c $jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

That will extract just the MANIFEST.MF file from the zip archive, and output it to standard output.

You can thus skip the whole temp-dir process entirely.

Answer (score 3):

I find this line:

```
sed -ne '/^Class-Path:/,$p' META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | sed -e 's/^Class-Path: //' -e 's/^ //' | tr -d '\n' | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Incredibly confusing to read. Surely, there has to be a simpler / less hacky way of doing this? I don't know bash but it jumps out as a code smell anyways...

Answer (score 3):

### JAR extraction

A lot of the headache comes from handling the temporary file.  You have to find a temporary directory (which should be done using [`mktemp(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp)) and clean up the mess afterwards, even in case of failure.

All you want is to process the contents of `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.  Ideally, you should extract the text to standard output to be piped for further processing.  Unfortunately, Java's `jar` command has no such capability.

Fortunately, the [JAR File Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) says that the format is based on the popular ZIP file format.  Therefore, you can use [`unzip(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip), which *does* support a `-c` option to extract to standard output.

### Text processing

Your code prints every word after `Class-Path:` until the end of the file.  If other entries appear in `MANIFEST.MF` after the `Class-Path` line, their contents will be printed too!

I suggest writing a short AWK script to unfold the continuation lines.  Then find the `Class-Path` entry, split it into one line per word, and omit the first line.  You *could* try to do everything in one AWK script, but I recommend separating concerns.

### Suggested solution

```
unzip -q -c "$jar" META-INF/MANIFEST.MF |

        # Unfold continuation lines
        # (This prepends an empty line, but that won't matter)
        awk '/^[^ ]/ { print BUF; BUF=$0 }
             END     { print BUF }
             /^ /    { sub(" *", ""); BUF = BUF $0 }' |

        # Get Class-Path entry
        grep '^Class-Path: ' |

        # Split into one line per word
        tr ' ' '\n' |

        # Omit the "Class-Path:" entry name itself
        tail +2
```